# How to add padding below xaxis label in ApexChart.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, apexcharts

I am using ApexCharts.js in React and unable to find a way to get some space between the xaxis and the bottom border. Can someone please help me out with this?
[An image of the spacing issue I am having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCPgP.png)

Comment: Can you please add everything that you have tried so far? Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

Increase the bottom padding of `grid`

```js
grid: {
  padding: {
    bottom: 20
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add a padding

```
<apex-tag style="padding-bottom: 3px;"><apex-tag>
```